# Sending work to a pool of workers that need initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, executor

I have a problem that seems close to what `Executor`s and Thread pools do, however I can't seem to make it exactly fit. Basically I have workers which take a bit of time to initialize and that I'd like to pool, and once they are ready I use them to do work. I need to do this in a Thread :

```
worker = buildExpensiveWorker();
worker.doWork(work1);
worker.doWork(work2);
worker.doWork(work3);
...
```

While an Executor only allows me to do this :

```
doWork(work1);
doWork(work2);
doWork(work3);
...
```

Will I need to write my own Thread pool ? It feels like a shame to rewrite what is already well done. Or will I need to use `ThreadLocal` to hold my workers, and manage them from inside the `Runnable`'s run() method ?

Comment: You should probably use `ThreadPoolExecutor` and refactor your current design so it fits without custom "workers". If you don't want to do this, then yes you'll __probably__ need to implement your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about actually initializing the Thread objects prior to them being available for use, take a look at ThreadPoolExecutor.setThreadFactory:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setThreadFactory(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory)

You can provide your own implementation create a thread in any manner you want, including creating custom Thread subclasses and/or custom initialization.

I would say however, that if your initialization is expensive, you should probably try to configure the executor to keep the actual threads alive as long as possible (ie, set the keep alive time rather high, and try to spin up all the threads you need right away, and take the hit up front).

EDIT:  Using a thread local (as mentioned in the comments):

```
public class ThreadData {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> data = new ThreadLocal<String>();
}

public class InitializingThread extends Thread {
    public InitializingThread(Runnable r) {
        super(r);
    }

    public void run() {
        ThreadData.data.set("foo");
        super.run();
    }
}

public class InitializingThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new InitializingThread(r);
    }
}

ThreadPoolExecutor executor = ...;
executor.setThreadFactory(new InitializingThreadFactory());
executor.execute(...);
```

And then in your Runnable:

```
public void run() {
     String s = ThreadData.data.get();
}
```

Also, this approach (as opposed to using using Thread.currentThread() and casting) has the advantage of being able to actually be used with any Thread implementation (including the default), or without a thread (directly calling the .run() method after setting the value in the ThreadLocal).  You could also easily change "ThreadLocal" to "InheritableThreadLocal", and set it once before submitting anything to the thread pool.  All child threads would inherit the value from their parent thread (the one which created the pool).

It's important to note that the "run" method of a given thread will only ever executed once, even when in a thread pool, so this guarantees that your initialization routine happens on a per thread basis.

Comment: My problem was that the Runnables are executed in a stateless fashion. Are you suggesting to provide my own ThreadFactory and then use Thread.getCurrentThread() to get my worker ? This would work.

Comment: Yep.   Create your own thread implementation with whatever state you need and cast Thread.currentThread() to your class.  An alternative would be to create a public static ThreadLocal instance somewhere, and have your thread class populate it in the run method before calling super.run().  This would bind your Runnable to the ThreadLocal rather than the actual Thread implementation class, but it's just a matter of style really.

Comment: @Matt: great answer, many thanks and 1+ up-vote. Do you have a link on use of using a ThreadLocal for this problem?

Comment: It is possible to create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with pre-initialized workers? In your example, the thread creation and initialization is happening when `executor.execute()` is invoked. I want to send a job to a queue where the thread pool contains workers initialized at thread pool creation time, and can pick up the work immediately.